# como pegar url de requisições do console em javascript

Tags: javascript, json

galera eu preciso pegar a url de um get do console eu quero saber isso pq eu tenho um iframe que eu preciso pegar a url de um get dele so que na url existe uma variavel randomica que fica mudando sempre que dou reload existe alguma maneira de eu pegar a url direto do console [image: por exemplo a url dessa requisição que esta no console]

Comment: Elvis, bem-vindo ao [pt.so]! A meu ver não está muito claro o que você está querendo obter. O console registra as requisições para que você possa inspecionar, mas não é algo que faz parte do escopo de uma página. Você quer monitorar as requisições feita pela página do `iframe`? Quer executar algo com isso ou apenas inspecionar no console? Como está fazendo isto agora? Por favor, tente esclarecer esses pontos para podermos ajudar você melhor.

Comment: tipo isso por exemplo, eu tenho um iframe na minha pagina, esse iframe faz um get, eu preciso pegar a url deste get mais nesta url tem uma variavel que muda a cada vez que a pagina é visitada e essa variavel funciona como uma chave entende, a variavel é mudada atraves do javascript do iframe e como eu n posso mudar o codigo do iframe n tenho como pegar esta variavel mudada, a unica maneira de conseguir seria pegando o get do console com todas as variaveis já certinhas

Comment: A não ser que você esteja implementando uma extensão para o Chrome, não creio que você possa acessar informações do console a partir da sua página principal. Além disso, se a sua página está em um domínio diferente daquela do `iframe`, então por questões de segurança vai ser impossível você interagir com ela em JavaScript.

Comment: A que tipo de variável você se refere? Seria um parâmetro de URL ou uma variável global da página? Caso você tenha acesso ao `iframe`, supondo que não haja restrições de segurança, você poderia listar todas as variáveis e identificar o nome dessa variável que você procura. Ou ainda se essa requisição usar JQuery, você pode adicionar um *hook* global para escutar às requisições AJAX. Mas teria que saber mais detalhes para dizer exatamente o que é possível e o que não é.

Comment: psé mais o iframe n deixa eu fazer modificações vou dar algum jeito de fazer diferente.

Answer (score 0):

você pode obter os parametros da URL atravez do objeto, window, segue um exemplo abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue também outra função para conseguir os parâmetros no formato de objeto.

```
 function getQueryParams() {
   var queryParameters = window.location.search.split('+').join(' ');

   var params = {},
       tokens,
       re = /[?&]?([^=]+)=([^&]*)/g;

   while (tokens = re.exec(queryParameters)) {
     params[decodeURIComponent(tokens[1])] = decodeURIComponent(tokens[2]);
   }

   return params;
 }
```

Comment: tipo não sao as variaveis da minha url o get é feito atraves de uma pagina externa queria pegar as variaveis dessa url externa lembrando que esse get é feito por um iframe por isso n consigo pegar direto pelo meu javascript